# Facebook Message API

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

I am creating a Facebook message. For the moment I am sending a message with title, subtitle, image and a button using the following message data.

```
var messageData = {
                    recipient: {
                        user_ref: recipientId
                    },
                    message: {
                        attachment: {
                            type: 'template',
                            payload: {
                                template_type: 'generic',
                                sharable: true,
                                image_aspect_ratio: 'square',
                                elements: [ {
                                        title: new_title,
                                        subtitle: messageText,
                                        image_url: new_image_url,
                                        default_action: {
                                            type: 'web_url',
                                            url: new_link,
                                            webview_height_ratio: 'tall'
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        metadata: "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_METADATA"
                    }
                };
```

I want to able to add a video in the same Facebook message. Is it possible?
So far, I have seen you can send videos in a separate message but not using a template with title, image, subtitle, etc (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-messages#sending_attachments)

Answer (score 1):

The generic template does not support videos. You can use the attachment API or media template (preferred) to send videos. 
However, generic templates with an option to show an actual video are not available.

Comment: Yeah, I have seen I can use the media template. I can send videos but I can't see how to add a title and a subtitle

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a generic template style, but with an option to show an actual video. This simply is not available.